# How to use PHP cURL to send images with the correct Content-Type?

Tags: php, curl

**Objective:**

I want to send multiple images using multipart/form-data.  Below is a snippet of my code.

**Problem:**

On one PC, the multipart attachment is sent by the correct MIME header Content-Type: image/jpeg, but on another PC, the MIME header is Content-Type: application/octet.

**Question:**

How can I force cURL to set the correct Content-Type header for the MIME content?

```
$ch = curl_init();

$params = array('name' => '@D:\globe.jpg');  

$base_url = "https://example.com"."?".varEncode($test_data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$base_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: image/jpeg"));
```

So specify Content-Type headers specifically for file uploads, use:

```
$params = array('name'=>'@D:\globe.jpg;type=image/jpeg');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
```

Comment: But this will change the Content-Type on HTTP header, not the MIME multipart header.  

PHP cURL seems to use magic.mime to detect the file type and auto-magically add the Content-Type header.  Unfortunately, the magic.mime cannot detect a lot of file types and simple use application/octet-stream.

Comment: You can also set a custom file name:`@D:\globe.jpg;type=image/jpeg;filename=my_picture.jpg`