# How to set multiple Content-Types?

Tags: php, curl

How to set multiple Content-Types? I have to pass an array to request body. That array contains a text and an image in binary.

```
curl_setopt($apiCon, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'status' => rawurlencode($status), 
    'photo' => $photoInBinary
));
curl_setopt($apiCon, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Host: api.mixi-platform.com', 
    'Authorization: OAuth ' . $accessToken, 
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'
));
```

The problem is the host doesn't understand the format of the image, so I need to pass more content type 'image/jpg' but I don't know where to put it.

The above code works but it posts only the status.

**Update:**
Ok, my goal is to post a status with a photo to a social network page.

For more information, read this:
http://developer.mixi.co.jp/en/connect/mixi_graph_api/mixi_io_spec_top/voice-api/#toc-10

This is my code. It works but post only the status, not photo.

```
    $apiCon = curl_init(self::API_POST_STATUS_WITH_PHOTO);
    curl_setopt($apiCon, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($apiCon, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($apiCon, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($apiCon, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('status' => rawurlencode($status), 'photo' => $photoInBinary));
    curl_setopt($apiCon, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: api.mixi-platform.com', 'Authorization: OAuth ' . $accessToken, 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
    $result = curl_exec($apiCon);        
    curl_close($apiCon);
```

Comment: It is always a great idea when asking a question, to merely  describe your goal, using plain language, *without using terms you don't understand*.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074936/how-to-use-php-curl-to-send-images-with-the-correct-content-type

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel, I understood him. He means the `Content-Type` header of the file "part" of the `multipart/form-data` body. He uses these terms properly.

Comment: @FrancisAvila everyone can understood him, but a couple of deleted answers is a sign that the question asked improperly. Had he asked "how to upload a file using curl", he'd got right answers immediately.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: No, I don't mean how to post an image with the content type 'image/jpg'. I mean post a text AND an image in binary (not a file path).

Comment: that's what you had to ask. It doesn't matter though to go into such details, as multipart implies to have urlencoded part as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try not encoding your status field (i.e., remove `rawurlencode`). This is a double-encode and possibly this is why your host is complaining.

(As an aside, you don't need to set the content-type header explicitly; CURL will do that.)

If this isn't enough, you either have to rearrange your request to use CURL's magic file upload mechanism, or you have to construct the entire multipart/form-data string by yourself.

This is how CURL's magic file mechanism works (from the documentation to [`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. To post a file, prepend a filename with @ and use the full path. The filetype can be explicitly specified by following the filename with the type in the format ';type=mimetype'. This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data. As of PHP 5.2.0, value must be an array if files are passed to this option with the @ prefix.

The only way to pass the content-type of a specific field in a multipart/form-data POST using CURL is with this syntax for the field value: `@filepath;type=mime/type`.

**If your `$photoInBinary` started life in a file, simply pass the filename in the above format to CURL instead of opening the file and reading in the data.**

However, **if you created the photo yourself in memory, you need to write that to a temporary file**.  Below is how you might do that:

```
function curlFileUploadData($data, $type='') {
    // $data can be a string or a stream
    $filename = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'curlupload-');
    file_put_contents($filename, $data);
    $curlparam = "@{$filename}";
    if ($type) {
        $curlparam .= ";type={$type}";
    }
    return array($curlparam, $filename);
}

list($curlparam, $tmpfile) = curlFileUploadData('thedata', 'image/bmp');

// You can see the raw bits CURL sends if you run 'nc -l 9999' at a command line first
$c = curl_init('http://localhost:9999');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('status' => 'good', 'photo' => $curlparam));
curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);

unlink($tmpfile); // REMEMBER TO DO THIS!!!!
```

Note that CURL will set the filename parameter on the multipart file upload. Be sure the host doesn't use this for anything important. As far as I know there's no way to override the filename CURL sends--it will always be exactly what was given.

If you are not willing to create a temporary file and you must use CURL, you will have to create the entire multipart/form-data body as a string in memory, and give that to CURL as a string to `CURL_POSTFIELDS`, and manually set the content-type header to `multipart/form-data`. This is left as an exercise for the reader. By this time you should consider using the [HTTP extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.http.php) instead, or even `fopen` with `stream_context_create()` to set the http method and headers.