# Trouble with php cURL library and REST POST request

Tags: php, rest, post, curl

I'm having trouble with a REST POST request after the API to which I'm posting published the final release of their API. It was working without incident, and I've been told that with the new version the server is more strict regarding the type being 'application/json'. The following cli curl command works swimmingly:

```
cat json.txt|curl -v -k -u user:password -F 'exchangeInstance=@-;type=application/json'  https://my.url.here
```

However, I need to execute this in code. Using the php curl libraries I've got a simple test script up that looks like this:

```
  $post = array(
    "exchangeInstance" => $json_string,
    "type" => "application/json",
  );
  $url = 'myurlhere';

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pass");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

  var_dump($post);
  var_dump($result);
  echo $result;
  var_dump($info);
```

As I read the documentation, the Content-type in the header should automatically be set to 'multipart/form' if I pass an array as CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, and then I'm setting the type for the element pass to 'application/json' in the array.

However, the api has had no POST requests from me. And I'm getting an error from them that clearly indicates that they are receiving a GET request. How can this possibly be? What am I missing?

Comment: you've got followlocation=true. if the server is doing a redirect, that redirected-to url will be fetched via GET, even if you started out with a POST to begin with. turn it off and see what you get back.

Comment: Wow. This certainly fits what I'm dealing with, but I can't find any documentation on it. Any leads? I have a feeling I'm being authenticated at point A, and redirected to point B. I'm being redirected to a specific port, but I'm using the same url as in the CLI command.

Answer (score 1):

curl `-F` !== `-d`

```
$post = array(
    "exchangeInstance" => sprintf('@%s;type=application/json', $json_string),   
);
```

Comment: This is very interesting. Thank God for smart people. I'm sure it's part of the problem, but not all at the moment. I'll post back when I know more - Thank you!

Comment: So, this doesn't really work unless I'm passing a path to a file.  Otherwise it sends a string appended with an @ symbol... I'm not finding a way to set the content-type of the individual mime multi-part header without passing it a file. It does seem to me there should be a better way than to write my string to a temp file, then send it to the curl library... any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074936/how-to-use-php-curl-to-send-images-with-the-correct-content-type